# Lenovo T495/Intel Wireless-AC 9260

Tags: wifi, drivers, intel, wlan, lenovo

We just switched to the T495 from the A485 as our laptop of choice. We are imaging them to Win10x64 1903 using SCCM, with the drivers provided by Lenovo. The wifi (Intel Wireless-AC 9260) is not working in any of them with a "Code 10: Device Cannot Start" error. We have tried the latest drivers from Lenovo (21.20.1.1) as well as the latest drivers from Intel (21.30.3.2), neither work. To check, I booted one up straight from Lenovo. It is running 20.120.0.100, and wifi works. I downloaded that exact driver from Lenovo, put it on one of the machines that is not working, and it is still not able to start the device.
[Error Code we are getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbU3h.png)
[Older driver not working on an imaged laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc1Bm.png)
[Older driver **working** on a laptop straight from Lenovo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUcQM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Last month's cumulative Windows update was the culprit. Had to uninstall the update, reboot (long reboot), uninstall the device w/ removing drivers, reboot (short reboot), and maybe disable/re-enable the device (some devices required, some did not).

Thanks to Don W. on Spiceworks for the link:
https://www.windowslatest.com/2019/09/15/windows-10-kb4515384-breaks-network-adapter/

This "troubleshooter package" from Microsoft allows you to hide the update so it doesn't come back:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3183922/how-to-temporarily-prevent-a-windows-update-from-reinstalling-in-windo